# Filter image that contains NaNs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filtering, nan

I have a 2d array (`doubles`) representing some data, and it has a bunch of `NaNs` in it. The contour plot of the data looks like this:

[image: prefiltered]

All of the white spaces are `NaNs`, the gray diamond is there for reference, and the filled contour shows the shape of my data. When I filter the data with `imfilt`, the `NaNs` significantly chew into the data, so we end up with something like this:

[image: postfiltered]

You can see that the support set is significantly contracted. I can't use this, as it has chewed into some of the more interesting variations on the edges (for reasons specific to my experiments, those edges are important).

Is there a function to filter within an island of `NaNs` that treats edges similar to edges of rectangular filtering windows, instead of just killing the edges? Sort of like an `nanmean` function, except for convolving images?

Here is my filter code:

```
filtWidth = 7;
imageFilter=fspecial('gaussian',filtWidth,filtSigma);
%convolve them
dataFiltered = imfilter(rfVals,imageFilter,'symmetric','conv');
```

and the code for plotting the contour plot:

```
figure
contourf(dataFiltered); hold on
plot([-850 0 850 0 -850], [0 850 0 -850 0], 'Color', [.7 .7 .7],'LineWidth', 1); %the square (limits are data-specific)
axis equal
```

There is some code at the Mathworks file exchange ([ndanfilter.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20417-ndnanfilter-m)) that comes close to what I want, but I believe it only interpolates `NaNs` that are sprinkled on the *interior* of an image, not data showing this island-type effect.

Note: I just found [nanconv.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41961-nanconv/content/nanconv.m), which does exactly what I want, with a very intuitive usage (convolve an image, ignoring `NaN`, much like `nanmean` works). I've made this part of my accepted answer, and include a comparison to the performance of the other answers.

**Related questions**

[Gaussian filtering a image with Nan in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697532/gaussian-filtering-a-image-with-nan-in-python)

Comment: what does data look like? is it just a 2D double?

Comment: Yes, 2d double. Updated question to make this explicit.

Comment: `imFilt` for the last line...do you mean `imFilter`?

Comment: can you also post how you plotted your image?

Comment: OK will add more details: and yes, I misnamed that variable will fix that too.

Comment: I think I got a solution, just need to plot it XD

Comment: Let me know if that works for you. If so, kindly accept it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technique I ended up using was the function [nanconv.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41961-nanconv/content/nanconv.m) at Matlab's File Exchange. It does exactly what I was looking for: it runs the filter in a way that ignores the `NaNs` just the way that Matlab's built-in function `nanmean` does. This is a hard to decipher from the documentation of the function, which is a tad cryptic.

Here's how I use it:

```
filtWidth = 7;
filtSigma = 5;
imageFilter=fspecial('gaussian',filtWidth,filtSigma);
dataFiltered = nanconv(data,imageFilter, 'nanout');
```

I'm pasting the `nanconv` function below (it is covered by [the BSD license](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/view_license?file_info_id=41961)). I will post images etc when I get a chance, just wanted to post what I ended up doing for anyone curious about what I did.

**Comparison to other answers**

Using [gnovice's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29834391/1886357) the results look intuitively very nice, but there are some quantitative blips on the edges that were a concern. In practice, the extrapolation of the image beyond the edges led to many spuriously high values at the edges of my data.

Using [krisdestruction's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833326/1886357) of replacing the missing bits with the original data, also looks pretty decent (especially for very small filters), but (by design) you end up with unfiltered data at the edges, which is a problem for my application.

**nanconv**

```
function c = nanconv(a, k, varargin)
% NANCONV Convolution in 1D or 2D ignoring NaNs.
%   C = NANCONV(A, K) convolves A and K, correcting for any NaN values
%   in the input vector A. The result is the same size as A (as though you
%   called 'conv' or 'conv2' with the 'same' shape).
%
%   C = NANCONV(A, K, 'param1', 'param2', ...) specifies one or more of the following:
%     'edge'     - Apply edge correction to the output.
%     'noedge'   - Do not apply edge correction to the output (default).
%     'nanout'   - The result C should have NaNs in the same places as A.
%     'nonanout' - The result C should have ignored NaNs removed (default).
%                  Even with this option, C will have NaN values where the
%                  number of consecutive NaNs is too large to ignore.
%     '2d'       - Treat the input vectors as 2D matrices (default).
%     '1d'       - Treat the input vectors as 1D vectors.
%                  This option only matters if 'a' or 'k' is a row vector,
%                  and the other is a column vector. Otherwise, this
%                  option has no effect.
%
%   NANCONV works by running 'conv2' either two or three times. The first
%   time is run on the original input signals A and K, except all the
%   NaN values in A are replaced with zeros. The 'same' input argument is
%   used so the output is the same size as A. The second convolution is
%   done between a matrix the same size as A, except with zeros wherever
%   there is a NaN value in A, and ones everywhere else. The output from
%   the first convolution is normalized by the output from the second 
%   convolution. This corrects for missing (NaN) values in A, but it has
%   the side effect of correcting for edge effects due to the assumption of
%   zero padding during convolution. When the optional 'noedge' parameter
%   is included, the convolution is run a third time, this time on a matrix
%   of all ones the same size as A. The output from this third convolution
%   is used to restore the edge effects. The 'noedge' parameter is enabled
%   by default so that the output from 'nanconv' is identical to the output
%   from 'conv2' when the input argument A has no NaN values.
%
% See also conv, conv2
%
% AUTHOR: Benjamin Kraus (bkraus@bu.edu, ben@benkraus.com)
% Copyright (c) 2013, Benjamin Kraus
% $Id: nanconv.m 4861 2013-05-27 03:16:22Z bkraus $

% Process input arguments
for arg = 1:nargin-2
    switch lower(varargin{arg})
        case 'edge'; edge = true; % Apply edge correction
        case 'noedge'; edge = false; % Do not apply edge correction
        case {'same','full','valid'}; shape = varargin{arg}; % Specify shape
        case 'nanout'; nanout = true; % Include original NaNs in the output.
        case 'nonanout'; nanout = false; % Do not include NaNs in the output.
        case {'2d','is2d'}; is1D = false; % Treat the input as 2D
        case {'1d','is1d'}; is1D = true; % Treat the input as 1D
    end
end

% Apply default options when necessary.
if(exist('edge','var')~=1); edge = false; end
if(exist('nanout','var')~=1); nanout = false; end
if(exist('is1D','var')~=1); is1D = false; end
if(exist('shape','var')~=1); shape = 'same';
elseif(~strcmp(shape,'same'))
    error([mfilename ':NotImplemented'],'Shape ''%s'' not implemented',shape);
end

% Get the size of 'a' for use later.
sza = size(a);

% If 1D, then convert them both to columns.
% This modification only matters if 'a' or 'k' is a row vector, and the
% other is a column vector. Otherwise, this argument has no effect.
if(is1D);
    if(~isvector(a) || ~isvector(k))
        error('MATLAB:conv:AorBNotVector','A and B must be vectors.');
    end
    a = a(:); k = k(:);
end

% Flat function for comparison.
o = ones(size(a));

% Flat function with NaNs for comparison.
on = ones(size(a));

% Find all the NaNs in the input.
n = isnan(a);

% Replace NaNs with zero, both in 'a' and 'on'.
a(n) = 0;
on(n) = 0;

% Check that the filter does not have NaNs.
if(any(isnan(k)));
    error([mfilename ':NaNinFilter'],'Filter (k) contains NaN values.');
end

% Calculate what a 'flat' function looks like after convolution.
if(any(n(:)) || edge)
    flat = conv2(on,k,shape);
else flat = o;
end

% The line above will automatically include a correction for edge effects,
% so remove that correction if the user does not want it.
if(any(n(:)) && ~edge); flat = flat./conv2(o,k,shape); end

% Do the actual convolution
c = conv2(a,k,shape)./flat;

% If requested, replace output values with NaNs corresponding to input.
if(nanout); c(n) = NaN; end

% If 1D, convert back to the original shape.
if(is1D && sza(1) == 1); c = c.'; end

end
```

Comment: Note, a recent submission to the File Exchange has a slightly more flexible implementation:  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20417-ndnanfilter-m

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to replace the NaN values with nearest-neighbor interpolates using [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html) (or [`TriScatteredInterp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html?refresh=true) in older MATLAB versions) before performing the filtering, then replacing those points again with NaN values afterward. This would be akin to filtering a full 2-D array using the `'replicate'` argument as opposed to the `'symmetric'` argument as a boundary option for `imfilter` (i.e. you're replicating as opposed to reflecting values at the jagged NaN boundary).

Here's what the code would look like:

```
% Make your filter:
filtWidth = 7;
imageFilter = fspecial('gaussian', filtWidth, filtWidth);

% Interpolate new values for Nans:
nanMask = isnan(rfVals);
[r, c] = find(~nanMask);
[rNan, cNan] = find(nanMask);
F = scatteredInterpolant(c, r, rfVals(~nanMask), 'nearest');
interpVals = F(cNan, rNan);
data = rfVals;
data(nanMask) = interpVals;

% Filter the data, replacing Nans afterward:
dataFiltered = imfilter(data, imageFilter, 'replicate', 'conv');
dataFiltered(nanMask) = nan;
```

Comment: do you have any understanding of the difference between using `imfilter(....'replicate')` and the function `nanconv` (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41961-nanconv)? They are both giving similar results, but I'm not really understanding how either one works, frankly.

Comment: looks very promising (my version I only have `TriScatteredInterp` but it works the exact same). Am presently comparing it to performance of `nanconv`, in practice....

Comment: @neuronet I'm not familiar with `nanconv` or the underlying code is uses, so I'm not certain yet what the differences might be.

Comment: thanks I will look into it, might be tomorrow. Would prefer native Matlab code, though, so will go with your answer everything else being equal.

Comment: @gnovice Wouldn't the interpolation change the effect of the filter has on the data?

Comment: @gnovice so basically we are 1) *extrapolating* at the edges to fill the entire matrix with numbers instead of `NaNs` (while we use a function called interpolate, it seems more like extrapolation way beyond the actual data), 2) running the filter on the new matrix, and 3) apply a mask to restrict the results to the original support set. This seems to work pretty well. If you don't mind I'll edit your answer, with some figures, to make it crystal clear...

Comment: @gnovice: would you mind if I replaced your `scatteredInterpolant` with `TriScatteredInterp`? The latter is available on more (i.e., older) versions of Matlab. Will get to it this weekend, am making images of every step in your algorithm from my data it should be pretty cool...

Comment: @neuronet: Adding some figures using the data from your question would be good. I'll edit in a mention of `TriScatteredInterp` for older versions.

Comment: @krisdestruction: That's always an issue at boundaries, and as neuronet points out the interpolation done here is more of an extrapolation of data into the regions filled with NaNs.The choice of how this extrapolation is done will certainly change the results of the filtering at the edges of the non-NaN data.

Comment: @gnovice Well yes I agree, and obviously the method depends on the OP's preference of the edge cases. However I was asking about the non NaN data. Since I'm not familiar with `scatteredInterpolant` can I assume the non-nan data in the middle of the output of our methods will be the same?

Comment: @krisdestruction yes it is the same. It only interpolates where there are no data points. I have been playing with this a lot today, and while it looks intuitively good, quantitatively the edges are a bit weird, as filtering the extrapolated image amplifies little variations at the edges. The `nanconv` function I found seems to work a bit better, much more like nanmean in that it simply *ignores* the nans, much like the `nanmean` built-in function. It is really a quite clever function. Will post this as a separate answer most likely, so busy with work (where I'm analyzing data like this :)).

Comment: @neuronet Okay in that case can you post a separate answer and accept that one? That way future viewers will be able to see the answer you used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay without using your plot function, I can still give you a solution. What you want to do is find all the new `NaN`'s and replace it with the original unfiltered data (assuming it is correct). While it's not filtered, it's better than reducing the domain of your contour image.

```
% Toy Example Data
rfVals= rand(100,100);
rfVals(1:2,:) = nan;
rfVals(:,1:2) = nan;

% Create and Apply Filter
filtWidth = 3;
imageFilter=fspecial('gaussian',filtWidth,filtWidth);
dataFiltered = imfilter(rfVals,imageFilter,'symmetric','conv');
sum(sum(isnan( dataFiltered ) ) )

% Replace New NaN with Unfiltered Data
newnan = ~isnan( rfVals) & isnan( dataFiltered );
dataFiltered( newnan ) = rfVals( newnan );
sum(sum(isnan( rfVals) ) )
sum(sum(isnan( dataFiltered ) ) )
```

Detect new `NaN` using the following code. You can also probably use the `xor` function.

```
newnan = ~isnan( rfVals) & isnan( dataFiltered );
```

Then this line sets the indices in `dataFiltered` to the values in `rfVals`

```
dataFiltered( newnan ) = rfVals( newnan );
```

Results

From the lines printed in the console and my code, you can see that the number of `NaN` in dataFiltered is reduced from 688 to 396 as was the number of `NaN` in `rfVals`.

```
ans =
   688
ans =
   396
ans =
   396
```

**Alternate Solution 1**

You can also use a smaller filter near the edges by specifying a smaller kernel and merging it after, but if you just want valid data with minimal code, my main solution will work.

**Alternate Solution 2**

An alternate approach is to pad/replace the `NaN` values with zero or some constant you want so that it will work, then truncate it. However for signal processing/filtering, you will probably want my main solution.

Comment: This will work, and is pretty good, though will introduce discontinuities and unusually high frequencies at the edge. Ideally, we could built something akin to `nanmean`, but a filter that does the apt filtering when convolving, but only to the data points that are not `NaN`. Will play around with your idea, post image of what it looks like...

Comment: I don't want to add zeros (that's what I was doing using a mask) but it pulls the values down at the edges....

Comment: @neuronet Right that's only an alternate solution and I know you don't want that. My main solution pulls the data that's missing from your main data.

Comment: @neuronet Another alternate approach is to use a smaller sized filter near the edges. While it's more accurate, there's more code involved.

Comment: @neuronet After playing around with it, if you still wish for me to elaborate on "Alternate Solution 1", just ping me by posting a comment. Otherwise if it helped you and it works, kindly accept the solution :)

Comment: yes of course I will accept if it helps and it works, no need to keep reminding me :) I am looking into something like `nanconvolve` to compare them. Alternate solution is pretty good, but Ockham's razor starts to rear its head. Like I said, looking into what seems most parsimonious alternate that convolves but ignoring `NaNs`.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41961-nanconv/content/nanconv.m

Comment: @neuronet Yup I know, I just find a lot of my answers go unaccepted even though it's correct so I tend to send 1 comment. Forgot that I already did. I don't know about `nanconvolve`, is it a builtin function?

Comment: @neuronet I see, interesting! Let me know if it works better for you, I can update my answer with it if it works for you.

Answer (score -3):

nanfilter does exactly the same thing with nanconv when filtering as long as the filter is the same. If you get the nan values before you use nanfilter and then add the back to the after-filtered matrix, you will get the same result with what you get from nanconv with the option 'nanout', as long as you use the same filter.

Comment: What is nanfilter? It hasn't been mentioned once in this page yet, I cannot find it as a built-in matlab function, and google reveals nothing. Perhaps you meant to add this as a comment?