# apply gaussian filtering on numpy array with nan value and then plot the image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a numpy 2d array (image) with values >=0.0 but there are some indices with value 'nan'. When I try to plot this figure it looks like the below image. The 0 in the image array becomes black and nan becomes white.

[image]

Now I want to apply gaussian smoothing on this array such that the after smoothing when I try to plot smoothed array, the nan values from the previous array appears white only.

Comment: Why do you think you need a Gaussian filter? There are other questions and answers to how to filter data that contains NaN (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/36307291/512111).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a gaussian filter of an image, any pixel close to a `nan` pixel will also turn into a `nan`, since its new value is the weighted sum over all neighboring pixels covered by the convolution kernel.

Therefore, smoothing this particular image using, for example, `scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter()` will turn a lot of your zero values into `nan`s and you'll lose a lot of information.

To smooth this (apparently binary) data, I would replace the `nan`s by some other value, of course maintaining contrast to the non-`nan` pixels. For example, turn the zeros into ones, and the `nan`s into zeros, then apply the filter.

Comment: [`astropy.convolution`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/convolution/) supports NaN aware Gaussian filtering.