# Python: How to remove pixel annotation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have an image file like below...

[image]

and I would like to remove all the annotation available in that image file. It is not clear how this must be done in Python. 
This is what I did;

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread("/path/to/image/1.png")
image_contours = np.zeros((img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 1), np.uint8)

image_binary = np.zeros((img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 1), np.uint8)

for channel in range(img.shape[2]):
    ret, image_thresh = cv.threshold(img[:, :, channel], 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)    
    contours = cv.findContours(image_thresh, 1, 1)[0]   
    cv.drawContours(image_contours, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 3)

contours = cv.findContours(image_contours, cv.RETR_LIST,
                           cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

cv.drawContours(image_binary, [max(contours, key = cv.contourArea)],
                -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv.imwrite("/path/to/save/save.png", image_binary)
```

I dont get the original image removed from annotation. But instead I get the one below...
What I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using masked median filtering in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold as mask
- Apply morphology to the mask to dilate the white letters
- Invert mask
- Make mask and inverted mask 3 channel images
- Median filter the image
- Apply mask to median filtered image
- Apply inverted mask to input image
- Add the two together
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read image
img = cv2.imread('xray.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold 
mask = cv2.threshold(gray,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# open and then dilate mask to make white regions slightly larger
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (25,25))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# invert mask
mask_inv = 255 - mask

# make mask and inverted mask 3 channel
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])
mask_inv = cv2.merge([mask_inv,mask_inv,mask_inv])

# median filter input image
median = cv2.medianBlur(img, 55)

# apply inverted mask to image
img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask_inv)

# apply mask to median
median_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(median, mask)

# add together
result = cv2.add(img_masked,median_masked)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('xray_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('xray_mask_inv.png', mask_inv)
cv2.imwrite('xray_median.png', median)
cv2.imwrite('xray_masked.png', img_masked)
cv2.imwrite('xray_median_masked.png', median_masked)
cv2.imwrite('xray_removed.png', result)

cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('mask_inv', mask_inv )
cv2.imshow('median', median)
cv2.imshow('img_masked', img_masked)
cv2.imshow('median_masked', median_masked)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

Inverse mask:

[image]

Median filtered image:

[image]

Masked median:

[image]

Inverse masked input:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the step by step explanation.

Comment: I exactly copy and paste your code..  however, I can still see the annotation...
result = cv2.add(img_masked,median_masked)
cv.imwrite("/pathtowrite/test.png", result)..

Comment: Are you saying you get something different or that my result is not good enough?

Comment: yes it works  well with the image I shared here. But the original image size is larger than 2mb and I couldnt upload in the stackoverflow due to upload limitation. Its not working with the original image. does the size plays a role? or I am missing something else?

Comment: Yes, the size is important. You need to adjust the medianBlur and the morphology for the size of the text you want to remove. The other alternative is to use the mask to do do inpainting. But the OpenCV and Skimage inpainting methods do not do well on large areas. They work on thin lines or scratches. But you can try them

Comment: You can make the original image downsample (downscale), calculate masked median, upsample her to original size and calculate add with original image. It is possible that such processing will be faster.

Comment: A better approach would get the contours and bounding boxes of the letters and use the dimensions of the largest bounding box of the letters as an estimate of the median filter size and morphology needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565277/python-image-processing-how-to-remove-certain-contour-and-blend-the-value-with/61642763#61642763